# Is 'lock (this)' suitable for synchronizing every member function?

Tags: c#, locking, this

I have a `Singleton` class which is highly dependent on the `XML` file it uses as database. At constructor, the `XML` file is read and a `FileSystemWatcher` is watching for any further changes.

Now if any changes happens, I will read data from `XML` file again but at this point non of class functions should be accessible until `XML` file is reloaded.

My question is can I simply uses `this` as synchronization object (while reloading `XML` file) and don't make any changes to functions instead of putting a big `lock` on every function ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lock(this)` is best avoided - there is an edge case that **some other unrelated code** could also lock it, perhaps causing even a deadlock.

A better approach is:

```
private readonly object lockObj = new object();
```

And then `lock(lockObj)` - since this is private you avoid this edge-case.

Another strategy is to load all the data into an immutable encapsulated object; then you can swap everything by updating a single reference; and a reference assignment is guaranteed to be atomic. This allows:

```
private SomeModel model;
public void Refresh() {
     SomeModel newModel = new ...
     // fully load etc
     ...
     model = newModel;
}
```

This works best if you always take a snapshot, i.e. Instead of

```
var foo = model.Foo;
var bar = model.Bar;
```

You use:

```
var snapshot = model;
var foo = snapshot.Foo;
var bar = snapshot.Bar;
```

Since now we know that Foo and Bar are from the same model.

Comment: Am I right here: Because I use `Singleton` pattern and it loads data in constructor, then I can simply change `_instance` (I mean the internal reference to a singleton object) to a new `MyClass` (singleton class) and everything is done.

Comment: @Xaqron - I was thinking encapsulate **inside** the singleton, but whatever works for you. Note that if you can "new" it, it isn't true singleton.

Answer (score 5):

Don't `lock` on `this`. Ever. This is because code that you don't have control over might lock on your object and lead to a very difficult to detect deadlock scenario.

Instead, use a dedicated `lock` object:

```
private readonly object locker = new object();
```

Then:

```
lock(locker) {
   // something something
}
```

Since `locker` is marked as `private`, you don't have to worry about code external to your object locking your object.

Comment: This is already I'm doing. The down-side in my scenario is every function would be like this: `myFunction() { lock(_privateLock) { // function body } // end of lock } // end of function`

Comment: Corollary: Don't lock on other people's objects, either.  They might have used `lock(this)`.  I think only locking on `private` (or maybe in some cases `internal` or `protected`) instances of a special object created specifically for locking is a good habit.  I agree with Jon Skeet that allowing locking on arbitrary objects [was a mistake](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/12/05/redesigning-system-object-java-lang-object.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

If the watcher is the only writer and your objects are only readers, a [ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) might be better. Be sure to read the remarks section.